# Replace all values in WHOLE dataframe if it matches an item in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe containing only dates. I wish to replace all the dates in the whole dataframe that match a date in my vector, not only one column:

```
holidays
[1] "2022-01-01" "2022-04-15" "2022-04-17" "2022-04-18" "2022-04-27" "2022-05-05" "2022-05-26" "2022-06-05" "2022-06-06" "2022-12-25" "2022-12-26" "2021-04-04"
[13] "2021-04-05" "2021-04-27" "2021-05-05" "2021-05-13" "2021-05-23" "2021-05-24" "2021-12-25" "2021-12-26"
```

I've only found solutions that delete the whole row if the date in my vector matches the date in my dataframe but I wish to only replace the value with NA, not delete anything.

Further, I would like to replace all the values in the WHOLE dataframe if it is a weekend day. I know how to check this for one column but the whole dataframe I can't seem to manage.

Hope you can help out! Many thanks

```
>dput(T0range)
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(18708, 18708, 18708, 18708, 18708,
    18708, 18709, 18709, 18709, 18709, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18715,
    18715), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(18709, 18709, 18709,
    18709, 18709, 18709, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18716, 18716,
    18716, 18716, 18716), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(18710,
    18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18711, 18711, 18711, 18711,
    18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(18711,
    18711, 18711, 18711, 18711, 18711, 18712, 18712, 18712, 18712,
    18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18718), class = "Date"), V5 = structure(c(18712,
    18712, 18712, 18712, 18712, 18712, 18713, 18713, 18713, 18713,
    18719, 18719, 18719, 18719, 18719), class = "Date"), V6 = structure(c(18713,
    18713, 18713, 18713, 18713, 18713, 18714, 18714, 18714, 18714,
    18720, 18720, 18720, 18720, 18720), class = "Date"), V7 = structure(c(18714,
    18714, 18714, 18714, 18714, 18714, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18715,
    18721, 18721, 18721, 18721, 18721), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(18715,
    18715, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18716,
    18722, 18722, 18722, 18722, 18722), class = "Date"), V9 = structure(c(18716,
    18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717,
    18723, 18723, 18723, 18723, 18723), class = "Date"), V10 = structure(c(18717,
    18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18718,
    18724, 18724, 18724, 18724, 18724), class = "Date"), V11 = structure(c(18718,
    18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18719, 18719, 18719, 18719,
    18725, 18725, 18725, 18725, 18725), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(18719,
    18719, 18719, 18719, 18719, 18719, 18720, 18720, 18720, 18720,
    18726, 18726, 18726, 18726, 18726), class = "Date"), V13 = structure(c(18720,
    18720, 18720, 18720, 18720, 18720, 18721, 18721, 18721, 18721,
    18727, 18727, 18727, 18727, 18727), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(18721,
    18721, 18721, 18721, 18721, 18721, 18722, 18722, 18722, 18722,
    18728, 18728, 18728, 18728, 18728), class = "Date"), V15 = structure(c(18722,
    18722, 18722, 18722, 18722, 18722, 18723, 18723, 18723, 18723,
    18729, 18729, 18729, 18729, 18729), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
    -15L), class = "data.frame")
    > dput(holidays)
    structure(c(18993, 19097, 19099, 19100, 19109, 19117, 19138,
    19148, 19149, 19351, 19352, 18721, 18722, 18744, 18752, 18760,
    18770, 18771, 18986, 18987), class = "Date")
```

Comment: Could you please share your example data with `dput()`? It's very useful to know if your dates are `Date` class or `POSIX` class or something else. Generally you can do replacement directly, like `df$x[df$x == y] <- NA` will replace the `x` value in `df` with `NA` whenever it is in `y`. The idea with dates is no different, `df$date_column[df$date_column %in% holidays] <- NA`, but it will require that you have a `class` match between your date column and your `holidays` vector... which is why I ask for more details.

Comment: Hello Gregor, i added the dput to the original question. In your example of df$date_column[df$date_column %in% holidays] <- NA this is again only for one column but I wish to check all the columns of the dataframe

Comment: Since they're all Date columns `T0range[T0range %in% holidays] <- NA` should do it. Your example data doesn't have any matches...

Comment: Hi Gregor, I also tried this. Date 18722 (or 05-04-2021) appears several times, mainly in the V8 column.. am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mm, looks like the data frame structure is messing with the date `%in% `operator. Hmmmm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the easiest way is to `lapply` across the columns:

```
T0range[] = lapply(T0range, function(x){ x[x %in% holidays] <- NA; x})
```

Comment: This is perfect! As long as it works then I'm happy. Thanks a bunch :) By any chance would you know the answer to my second question? Regarding the weekdays function and also replacing all values if it's a saturday or sunday?

Comment: DebbieOomen, look at the `weekdays` function that returns the week day for a particular date. For instance, something like `x[weekdays(x) %in% c("Sunday","Saturday")]`.

Comment: Same approach, something like `T0range[]  = lapply(T0range, function(x){ x[weekdays(x) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")] <- NA; x})`